# Routing Windows 10 trafic via MacBook as Internet router

Tags: windows-10, networking, macos, wireless-networking, router

I try to configure MacBook Pro (Mid 2015, macOS High Sierra, v.10.13.6) to work as an Internet router for Win 10 laptop.

My configuration:

Ethernet cable directly connects Win 10 laptop Ethernet port to MacBook ThunderBolt port by means of ThunderBolt Ethernet adapter. MacBook accesses Internet with Frigate StrongSwan VPN over WiFi.

To configure ThunderBolt Ethernet interface I tried several options that "MacBook System Preference / Network" provides.
Options "DHCP" and "DHCP with manual address" both do not work, so I finally came to use "Manual" configuration of ThunderBolt Ethernet interface , where I set:

IP Address: 192.168.0.17

Subnet Nask: 255.255.255.0

DNS Server: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

[image]

Router: I can not figure out router IP address. I tried to use address of WiFi router which I got from 'netstat -nr' output on my Mac:

```
$ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            link#13            UCS            99        0  ipsec0
default            192.168.1.1        UGScI           5        0     en0
default            link#11            UCSI            0        0 bridge0
8.8.4.4            link#13            UHWIi           8    11865  ipsec0
8.8.8.8            link#13            UHWIi           7     8148  ipsec0
10.10.10.14        10.10.10.14        UH              0        0  ipsec0
17.57.144.89       link#13            UHWIi           1       80  ipsec0
17.242.179.27      link#13            UHW3I           0       29  ipsec0     95
17.253.127.206     link#13            UHW3I           0       18  ipsec0     99
20.65.133.230      link#13            UHWIi           1     1207  ipsec0
40.99.169.162      link#13            UHW3I           0       22  ipsec0    186
40.126.53.16       link#13            UHW3I           0        3  ipsec0     58
52.96.57.98        link#13            UHW3I           0       29  ipsec0    125
52.96.121.194      link#13            UHWIi           1      350  ipsec0
52.96.121.242      link#13            UHW3I           0        8  ipsec0      3
52.168.117.171     link#13            UHW3I           0        3  ipsec0      6
104.18.32.7        link#13            UHWIi           1       50  ipsec0
104.18.37.228      link#13            UHW3I           0       98  ipsec0     73
104.18.40.222      link#13            UHWIi           1      798  ipsec0
104.18.41.158      link#13            UHW3I           0       10  ipsec0     38
104.18.131.236     link#13            UHWIi           1      183  ipsec0
104.26.9.177       link#13            UHWIi           1      182  ipsec0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              2      206     lo0
142.250.113.94     link#13            UHW3I           0      240  ipsec0    163
142.250.113.95     link#13            UHW3I           0      253  ipsec0    201
142.250.113.97     link#13            UHW3I           0       97  ipsec0     76
142.250.113.99     link#13            UHW3I           0       90  ipsec0     88
142.250.113.100    link#13            UHW3I           0       14  ipsec0     85
142.250.113.113    link#13            UHW3I           0       56  ipsec0    112
142.250.113.132    link#13            UHW3I           0      311  ipsec0     88
142.250.113.157    link#13            UHW3I           0       24  ipsec0     33
142.250.114.83     link#13            UHW3I           0       50  ipsec0    158
142.250.114.95     link#13            UHW3I           0      106  ipsec0     76
142.250.114.102    link#13            UHW3I           0       33  ipsec0    142
142.250.114.154    link#13            UHWIi           1       10  ipsec0
142.250.114.156    link#13            UHW3I           0       42  ipsec0    125
142.250.115.95     link#13            UHWIi           2      659  ipsec0
142.250.115.101    link#13            UHW3I           0      296  ipsec0     76
142.250.115.103    link#13            UHW3I           0        6  ipsec0     81
142.250.115.132    link#13            UHW3I           0      171  ipsec0    163
142.250.115.136    link#13            UHWIi           1     3710  ipsec0
142.250.115.139    link#13            UHWIi           1      225  ipsec0
142.250.115.156    link#13            UHW3I           0       40  ipsec0    131
142.250.115.157    link#13            UHW3I           0      514  ipsec0    171
142.250.138.95     link#13            UHW3I           0       10  ipsec0     55
142.250.138.154    link#13            UHW3I           0      450  ipsec0     84
142.251.116.113    link#13            UHWIi           1       26  ipsec0
142.251.116.148    link#13            UHW3I           0      231  ipsec0    125
142.251.116.149    link#13            UHW3I           0       46  ipsec0     84
142.251.116.154    link#13            UHW3I           0      793  ipsec0    158
142.251.116.155    link#13            UHW3I           0       80  ipsec0    138
142.251.116.156    link#13            UHWIi           2       55  ipsec0
142.251.116.188    link#13            UHWIi           1      137  ipsec0
146.75.104.193     link#13            UHWIi           1      390  ipsec0
149.154.167.92     link#13            UHWIi           6     4201  ipsec0
167.88.166.234     192.168.1.1        UGHS       160848    80453     en0
169.254            link#6             UCS             0        0     en0
169.254            link#5             UCSI            0        0     en4
172.64.144.177     link#13            UHWIi           1      470  ipsec0
172.64.155.141     link#13            UHW3I           0       21  ipsec0     32
172.64.155.249     link#13            UHWIi           2      257  ipsec0
185.137.235.93     link#13            UHWIi           1      275  ipsec0
192.0.73.2         link#13            UHW3I           0      243  ipsec0     34
192.168.0          link#5             UCS             1        0     en4
192.168.0.17/32    link#5             UCS             0        0     en4
192.168.0.18       88:a4:c2:f3:6d:41  UHLWIi          1    92896     en4   1157
192.168.1          link#6             UCS             2        0     en0
192.168.1.1/32     link#6             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.1.1        28:ff:3e:dd:4f:2d  UHLWIir         2      406     en0    748
192.168.1.3        cc:47:40:cb:f:58   UHLWI           0        3     en0
192.168.1.6        96:e4:87:ed:fa:67  UHLWI           0        3     en0    748
192.168.1.9/32     link#6             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.2          link#11            UC              1        0 bridge0
192.178.49.163     link#13            UHWIi           6     2688  ipsec0
192.178.50.35      link#13            UHWIi           2      114  ipsec0
194.226.130.227    link#13            UHWIi           1      389  ipsec0
198.252.206.25     link#13            UHWIi           1      417  ipsec0
216.239.32.116     link#13            UHWIi           3       96  ipsec0
224.0.0/4          link#13            UmCS            1        0  ipsec0
224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCSI           0        0     en4
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCSI           1        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
239.255.255.250    link#13            UHmW3I          0      736  ipsec0    145
255.255.255.255/32 link#13            UCS             0        0  ipsec0
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCSI            0        0     en4
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCSI            0        0     en0
```

Using default gateway 192.168.1.1 as a ThunderBolt Ethernet router results in a failure of *all* routing on MacBook, WiFi connection stops working.

On Win 10 laptop I use the following Ethernet settings:

IP: 192.168.0.18

Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

Default gateway: 192.168.0.17

Preferred DNS server: 192.168.0.17

[image]

Without specifying router on ThunderBolt, I get connection between Win10 and MacBook, that I can ping in both directions:

```
Pinging 192.168.0.17 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

 $ ping 192.168.0.18
PING 192.168.0.18 (192.168.0.18): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.18: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=1.283 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.395 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.18: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.250 ms
...
```

Yet I can not ping from Windows well-know public IP address, such 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 (OpenDNS), 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 (Cloudflare), 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google DNS)

Which means that MacBook has no route from 192.168.0.17 to the outside world. (Of course DNS does not work as well and obviously I can't test DNS before routing works).

How to set route from 192.168.0.17 to the outside world on MacBook?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to set up [Internet Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp1540/mac)? If you want to do it manually instead, have you enabled network forwarding on the Mac? Like with `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`. You will not need a default gateway (router) address on the thunderbolt ethernet of the Mac

Comment: `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`did not solve the problem. Does it need reboot? Will  IP forwarding be saved between reboots?

Comment: No, it shouldn't require reboot, but it looks like you have to add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it persistent. What do you need from this connection that Internet Sharing doesn't provide? You may need to do some extra configuration to the VPN for it to know how to reach the 192.168.0.0/24 network, unless you also set up NAT on the MacBook.

Comment: I did Internet Sharing on ThunderBolt Ethernet. My MacBook is a VPN client of StrongSwan Debian server. MacBook  connects to Internet with WiFi router, so VPN tunnel goes through WiFi connection.  On MacBook VPN works without any problems. Win 10 laptop can't be configured as a StongSwan VPN client, that's why I need Win traffic to be routed by MacBook to StrongSwan server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with StrongSwan, but it looks like it does support the windows VPN connection: https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/interop/windowsClients.html though it depends on your situation of course. Does it create a VPN network interface (like "Frigate" in your screenshot)? If so, you can usually just set: Share your connection from: [VPN interface] > To computers using: [thunderbolt]

Comment: In my case docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/interop/windowsClients.html  configuration doesn't work. And yes, Frigate is a VPN network interface, and you right - usually just setting: "Share your connection from: [VPN interface] > To computers using: [thunderbolt]" works. Unfortunately this dialog box do not show Frigate VPN ((